# Create igraph from dataframe columns

Tags: r, igraph

I try to make an igraph from dataframe columns called `routes$Source Airport` and `routes$Destination Airport`
I type in

```
g<-graph.formula("routes$Source Airport","routes$Destination Airport")
plot.igraph(g)
```

I'm not sure that is correct!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bad idea to have spaces in the names of your variables. Let's just use `source` and `dest` instead for our variable names:

```
dat <- data.frame(source=1:3, dest=c(3, 1, 1))
```

You can make and plot your graph with the `graph.data.frame` function:

```
g <- graph.data.frame(dat)
plot(g)
```

[image: graph]